# Swift - Spritekit: Adding a counter (high score calculator) when node touches bottom edge

Tags: ios, css, node.js, swift

i have my code setup so that when my ball node touches the bottom edge of the screen the program detects it. what i want, is for a var to increase by 1 everytime it touches the bottom edge, essentially a high score variable.

i have this so far, but it only prints "your score is 1." over and over everytime the node touches the bottom boundary. any help would be appreciated. cheers!

my code:

```
  func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    // 1. Create local variables for two physics bodies
    var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody
    var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody
    var counter = Int()

    // 2. Assign the two physics bodies so that the one with the lower category is always stored in firstBody
    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    } else {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }

    // 3. react to the contact between ball and bottom
    if firstBody.categoryBitMask == BallCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == BottomCategory {

        counter++

        println("Score is \(counter).")
    }
```

Comment: Where do you initialize the variable? And where is it's scope? Is it a local variable?

Comment: ummmmmmmm, im kinda new to terminology, ill update my code.

Comment: Where did you declare the variable (tell the compiler its name and type) and where do you initialize it (give it its first value)

Comment: isnt that the 5th line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you declare the variable counter inside the function `didBeginContact`. So everytime the function gets called, a new variable `counter`is created.

Declare and initialize counter outside of the function. Best would be in a singleton Scoresheet:

```
class Scoresheet {
  // Singleton
  static let sharedInstance = Scoresheet()
  var scoreCounter = 0
}
```

Increase the value with:
`Scoresheet.sharedInstance.scoreCounter++`

Comment: what do you mean?

class Scoresheet {
  // Singleton
  static
 let sharedInstance = Scoresheet()
  var scoreCounter = 0

Comment: yes. create a new file and call it ScoreSheet.swift. then insert the code shown above and save it. Then you can access it via Scoresheet.sharedInstance.scoreCounter from your code inside didBeginContact

Comment: still not liking the "static". saying "static properties are not allowed within struts..." ?

Comment: i got it working man, like you said i just declared the variable outside the didBeginContact section. works well. except the counter goes up by 2 each time not 1 lol

Comment: I did not give you a struct. maybe sideffect with your code. good to hear it works now. y

Comment: any idea why its increases by 2 each touch not one? it goes "1 23 45 67 89 ..."?

Comment: do you call counter++ anywhere else?

Comment: plz check if didBeginContact is called twice

Comment: this is also only called 1 time. first time it touches the boundary it counts 1, then 2 every bounce after that

Comment: I cant evaluate that from this point. maybe you want to provide your project so that we can look into it

Answer (score 0):

your code is correct because on any **SKSpriteNode** touch call this function

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact)
```

But you need to increase your score in this

```
 if firstBody.categoryBitMask == BallCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == BottomCategory {
     //TODO: Replace the log statement with display of Game Over Scene

  counter ++
  println("Score is \(counter).")
}
```

Try this may be helpfull .. Thanks

Comment: It is the same function, as far as I can see

Comment: yes I am saying .. but need to increase score in this .. because all your SKSpriteNode calling this function

Comment: this returns a value of 1, every touch. it does not increase